# Advantages of using curried functions over a normal function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, currying

Below is a specific use case of using a normal and a curried function. Are there any advantages for using either if you only using two arguments?

```
//Normal Function
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

//Curried Function
function add1(x) {
    return function add2(y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Closures have good advantage of keeping your code tidy and helpful

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small example:

```
let add = (x, y) => x + y;
let addc = x => y => x + y;

// add 5 to every element

result = [1,2,3,4,5].map(x => add(x, 5))  // dirty and tedious
result = [1,2,3,4,5].map(addc(5))         // nice and tidy
```

In general, curried functions allow to express the logic in a "point-free" style, that is, as a combination of functions, without using variables, arguments and similar constructs.